# cisco 2851 router: can't view switch ports

Tags: cisco, router, vlan

I want to setup vlans on a 2851, but I'm not sure how to access the switch ports. I can access or view them. Is there something I have to enable? I have some devices plugged into the switch ports and they are communicating with each other fine.

```
router(config)#do show ip int bri
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet0/1         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/0         10.1.1.1    YES manual up                    up
```

--edit:
I have a NME-XD-48ES-2S-P module installed. Is this module not capable of creating VLANs?

Comment: It's a little unclear as to what you are exactly looking for.  Are you trying to see what Vlans are created on your router and what ports are using them?  To do this you could run `show vlan`.  Or are you trying to see some other information.

Comment: I'm trying to configure vlans, but I cannot even figure out how to access the switch ports to add to a vlan. Maybe I should change the wording of my question to just "how to access\configure switch ports on a 2851"?

Comment: Does the Router have the NMD-36ESW EtherSwitch module? If not, then it doesn't have switch ports. It has two integrated 10/100/1000 Ethernet ports, but that doesn't make it a switch.

Comment: Is this question about HWIC-*ESW ports, NM-**ESW ports, or NME-**ES ports? It's not clear what you mean by "switch ports".

Comment: hmm I bet that's it, the module I have installed is a NME-XD-48ES-2S-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The etherswitch module is configured separately - here's a great doc matching almost exactly what you have:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/modules/ps2797/products_configuration_example09186a0080810449.shtml

In short, you need to connect to the switch module and configure it separately with the following command:

```
service-module gigabitEthernet 1/0 session
```